# Зачем еще нужен блок с классом row в bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Привет.

Вопросы по `bootstrap`.
Исходный код:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>HEADING</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col-md-4">Some text.........</p>
        <p class="col-md-4">Some text.........</p>
        <p class="col-md-4">Some text.........</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Посмотрел в devtools и увидел, что элемент с классом `row` имеет `margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;`, которые позволяют компенсировать `padding-left: 15px;` у левого элемента и `padding-right: 15px;` у правого элемента, которые имеют класс, например, `col-md-4`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном примере в `container` лежит блок `row`, в котором ВСЕ ТРИ параграфа плавающие. Чтобы блок row не «схлопнулся», у него создан псевдоэлемент:

```
.row:after, .row:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
```

У каждого псевдоэлемента задано `clear: both` – чтобы не давал схлопнуться блоку с классом `row`.
**Не понятно то, зачем ПЕРЕД параграфами ставить псевдоэлемент**. ПОСЛЕ зачем стоит – это понятно, схлопнуться блоку `row` не дает.

1. **Зачем у каждого псевдоэлемента задано `display: table`?** **Зачем еще нужен блок с классом `row`?**
2. **Зачем блоку с классом `container` заданы псевдоэлементы `before` и `after`?**

Answer (score 1):

Идеальный способ работы с HTML это использовать таблицы, boostrap создал свой фреймворк основываясь на этом.

Класс `row` то же самое, что и `<tr>`, если говорить грубо. Так же как в `<table>` вы задаете сколько будет ячеек в таблице `col-md-4` `col-md-4` `col-md-4` (похоже на td). В общем, должно быть 12 или 24, смотря как настроен bootstrap. `4 + 4 + 4 = 12`. После чего вы добавляете `row` (`<tr>`), чтобы организовать новую линию дизайна.

Comment: где пишут про эту аналогию? можете ссылку дать?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: вы написали "row тоже самое что и <tr> если говорить грубо". посмотрел в девтулс и увидел, что у row display:block задано. если взять таблицу, то без <tr> таблица работать НЕ будет, <tr> есть всегда, даже, если его руками не написать - браузер сам его допишет. если же взять бутстрап, то без блока с класом row все равно все работает. единственное это то, что текст смещается на 15 пикселей с левой стороны

Comment: Если говорить, о правельной работе с бутстрап, то использование row обязательное, иначе нет смысла во всем фреймворке

Comment: я проверил на этом простом примере, разметка которого приведена в вопросе. без row нормально отработало. по-моему, row служит только для того, чтобы текст вне и внутри row на одной линии по вертикали был расположен

Comment: @Dimon row служит для обнуления float, без этого вся верстка летит

Answer (score 0):

`:before` и `:after` нужны как для того, чтобы `row` не схлопнулся, так и для того чтобы он не залезал на верхний элемент, который может не иметь `float`
Ну и плюс ко всему, это компенсация паддингов у `col-xs/sm/md/lg`, растягивание крайних элементов